# Desktop notifications about shell command completed

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to enable desktop notification about shell process completed? I would be great to have notification only when I'm on different desktop and process take more than x seconds.
More precisely:

I would like to do it for every process I run in terminal, like running specs, compiling, deploying. I use gnome.

Answer (score 6):

there seems to be [several tools](https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu) and which is best depends on your desktop environment and notification daemon being used. There's even a library (libnotify) which could be harnessed to write your own tools. Short answer: yes, it's possible.

```
notify-send "This message will be displayed for 3 seconds" -t 3000

gmessage -center -nofocus -font 'Sans Bold 48' "Laundry Done"

zenity --warning --text="Laundry Done!"

kdialog --passivepopup "Laundry Done!"
```